# Why is my code showing this error (URI is not registered(settings|project settings||Schemas and DTDs)?

Tags: android, xml, string, uri

I just did update in my string.xml and each xml file for string.

I receive this error when I try to commit in android studio.

Here is the example of code for error:

```
<LinearLayout
    **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"** this is the error
    **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"** this is the error
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="joyporter.danielwirelesssoftware.com.fragment.support.TrackDeliveryFragment"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tracking Number"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/track_deliver_number"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="dIMz1m3cRw"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_track"
            android:text="@string/TrackButton"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        **<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"** this is the error.
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/receiver_btn_contact_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn_contact_courier"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope there is a solution for this error.

Comment: did you fixed this error?

Answer (score 1):

Go to "File > Project Structure > Modules", click "add" and then click "android" and "apply/ok". That should solve anyone having a similar problem but the comments for this question are not helping you.